# How to count number of rows that has a certain amount of duplicates

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with alot of messages, each with an unique messageid, and an non unique userid. I want to specifically count how many different userid's that has, say fewer than 40 messages. How would I do that?

The following give me the specific messages I want, but I just want to know how many they are.

```
select userid, count(*) as c from MessageType1 group by userid having c <40 order by c desc;
```

Ideally I would also love to get a plot of the number of messages for each of userid. Sorry if two questions is to much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
select distinct userid, count(*) as c from MessageType1 
group by userid having count(*) <40 order by c desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I got the following error:
Error: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: I've just edtied my answer. I have tried like this and its working fine.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.

select userid, count(DISTINCT) as c from MessageType1 group by userid having c <40 order by c desc;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the following error though: Error: DISTINCT aggregates must have exactly one argument

Did you mean DISTINCT(msgid) ?

Comment: I tried this and it seems like it counted every element somehow, thans though!

What i got:

999999555|1
999999888|1
999999902|1
999999945|1
999999988|1
999999989|1
999999990|1
999999991|1
999999992|1
999999993|1
999999995|1
999999997|1
999999998|1
999999999|1

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
select userid, count(msgId) as c 
 from MessageType1 
 group by userid, count(*) 
 having c <40 
 order by c desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got the following Error: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Just try removing count(*) from group by clause. .

Comment: Thank you allthough it seems like this lists all the messages instead of listing how many they are.

Comment: No, it will return you the count of messages per user where number of messages is > 40